# jQuery: Delay fadeOut div multiple times

Tags: jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

I tried to write some sloppy jQuery code for an inline-confirm "dialog". It works just fine, except that the `delay()` only runs one time for each it `#row_ID`. The delay is meant to fade out the "dialog" if the user doesn't interact with it within a specific time span. The "cancel" link works great every time.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the JS:

```
    $("a.i_delete").click(function() {

        var parent = $(this).attr("id");
        var parentRow = "#row_" + parent;
        var inlineConfirm = $('<div id="confirm_' + parent + '" class="inline_c"><a href="#cancel" class="ic_cancel">Cancel, I want to keep it</a><a href="/?id=' + parent + '" class="ic_confirm">Delete</a></div>').hide().fadeIn(500);

        $(parentRow).append(inlineConfirm).delay(3500).queue(function() {
            $("#confirm_" + parent).fadeOut(2000,function() {
                    $("#confirm_" + parent).remove();
                });
        });

            $("a.ic_cancel").click(function() {
                $("#confirm_" + parent).fadeOut(500,function() {
                        $("#confirm_" + parent).remove();
                    });

                return false;
            });

        return false;

    });
```

And here's the html:

```
    <div id="row_XXX" class="l_row">
        Bla bla bla <a href="/?id=XXX" id="XXX" class="i_delete" title="Delete link">Delete</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(parentRow)
    .append(inlineConfirm)
    .delay(3500)
    .queue(function(next) {
        $("#confirm_" + parent).fadeOut(2000,function() {
            $("#confirm_" + parent).remove();
        });

        // make sure the queue will continue by
        // calling next function on the queue
        next();
    });
```

Comment: What can I say, once again the users of Stack Overflow helps someone that probably shouldn't be working with the www :). Thank you, @Shef!

Answer (score 1):

Do you always want to append the inlineConfirm markup to parentRow? Instead set the html of the parent row. Every time you click on delete you are binding function to cancel click event. Please try the below code.

```
$("a.i_delete").click(function() {

        var parent = $(this).attr("id");
        var parentRow = "#row_" + parent;
        var inlineConfirm = $('<div id="confirm_' + parent + '" class="inline_c"><a href="#cancel" class="ic_cancel">Cancel, I want to keep it</a><a href="/?id=' + parent + '" class="ic_confirm">Delete</a></div>').hide().fadeIn(500);

        $(parentRow).html(inlineConfirm);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#confirm_" + parent).fadeOut(2000,function() {
                    $("#confirm_" + parent).remove();
                });
        }, 3500);

            $("a.ic_cancel").unbind('click').click(function() {
                $("#confirm_" + parent).fadeOut(500,function() {
                        $("#confirm_" + parent).remove();
                    });

                return false;
            });

        return false;

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ShankarSangoli. That didn't work right out of the box, now it removes the `#row_XXX` directly when I click the `delete` link.

Comment: I missed to add the time in setTimeout method. Now I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: Hm. This is what happens with your code: http://cl.ly/1i321l2N3a3V1m371x0u - This is what is supposed to  happen: http://cl.ly/2r3B341J18112e3k1R2e